# Using 2017 ACM Master Article Template with Scientific Word

Tags: acm

I cannot make 2017 ACM Template work with SW5.5. Here is the error message:

```
C:\sw55\TCITeX\web2c\pdfLaTeX.exe &pdflatex_ml C:/sw55/temp/swp0000.tex
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
(c:/sw55/temp/swp0000.tex
LaTeX2e <2003/12/01>
Babel <v3.8a> and hyphenation patterns for american, english, french, german, n
german, loaded.
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/acmart/acmart.cls
Document Class: acmart 2017/01/07 v1.28 Typesetting articles for Association of
 Computing Machinery
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2004/08/06 v2.20
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/totpages/totpages.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.25 \unless
            \ifdefined\collect@body
? r

! Undefined control sequence.
l.25 \unless\ifdefined
                      \collect@body
? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
! Missing { inserted.
\document ...up \@checkend {#2}\addto@envbody {#1}
                                                  \else \addto@envbody {#1\e...
l.73 \long\def\Collect@@Body#1\end#
                                   2{%
! Extra \else.
\document ...heckend {#2}\addto@envbody {#1}\else 
                                                  \addto@envbody {#1\end {#2...
l.73 \long\def\Collect@@Body#1\end#
                                   2{%
! Extra \fi.
\document ...else \addto@envbody {#1\end {#2}}\fi 
                                                  \process@envbody 
l.73 \long\def\Collect@@Body#1\end#
                                   2{%
)
Runaway argument?
2{\edef \begin@stack {\Push@Begins ##1\begin \end \expandafter \@gobble \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \document.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.173 \if@ACM@manuscript

(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
\citestyle #1->\ifcsname 
                         bibstyle@#1\endcsname \csname bibstyle@#1\endcsname...
l.269 \citestyle{acmnumeric}


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.269 \citestyle{acmnumeric}

! Extra \endcsname.
\citestyle #1->\ifcsname bibstyle@#1\endcsname 
                                               \csname bibstyle@#1\endcsname...
l.269 \citestyle{acmnumeric}

! Extra \fi.
l.270 \fi

(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Overfull \hbox (106.2502pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 269--10
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 bibstyle@acmnumeric
) (c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/oberdiek/hycolor.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/oberdiek/xcolor-patch.sty))
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty))

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 1057, version
               `2007/09/09' of package etexcmds,
               but only version
               `2007/05/06 v1.0 Providing prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)'
               is available.

(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/hyperref/puenc.def)
Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/ec-acmsmall/url.sty)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/generic/oberdiek/bitset.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 143, version
               `2007/09/09' of package infwarerr,
               but only version
               `2007/06/14 v1.1 Providing info/warning/message (HO)'
               is available.

(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/generic/oberdiek/intcalc.sty)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/generic/oberdiek/bigintcalc.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 140, version
               `2007/09/09' of package infwarerr,
               but only version
               `2007/06/14 v1.1 Providing info/warning/message (HO)'
               is available.

(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 3927, version
               `2007/09/29' of package kvsetkeys,
               but only version
               `2006/10/19 v1.1 Key value parser with default handler support (
HO)'
               is available.

(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 4524, version
               `2007/09/09' of package atbegshi,
               but only version
               `2007/06/06 v1.5 At begin shipout hook (HO)'
               is available.

)
*hyperref using default driver hpdftex*
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/hyperref/hpdftex.def)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/required/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/required/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/required/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/required/graphics/graphics.cfg)
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/required/graphics/pdftex.def)))
(c:/sw55/TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.sty
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=5000].
l.95 \catcode`\;=13 \catcode`\/=13 \catcode`\"=13 
                                                  \catcode`\>=13
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on swp0000.log.icle Template
```

Comment: Please paste the source code that results in this error message into your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your LaTeX system is very old.  You might need to update to Scientific word 6

PS  Just in case I contacted McKichan and asked whether they need help to make acmart working with Scientific Word 6.